# Change SSH banner which is grabbed by netcat

Tags: ssh, openssh, banner

I have installed openssh server. I want to disable banner which is shown when I do ::

`nc 0.0.0.0 22`

It shows something like this :: `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5` .

How to make it show something else or nothing at all ?

Comment: That's part of the SSH protocol (see `ssh_api.c`, `sshd.c`), so while you could fiddle around with the source and tell `sshd` to emit something else, you might break things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This banner

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5
```

is part of SSH protocol as described in chapter

> 4.2.  Protocol Version Exchange

of [RFC 4253](http://www.openssh.com/txt/rfc4253.txt):

> When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an
>      identification string.  This identification string MUST be
>
> ```
> SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
> ```

You can't get rid of the `SSH-2.0` part. The `softwareversion` part is used commonly for interoperability and it is also not good idea to remove it. The `comments` are optional and don't need to be there (but Debian puts them in by default).

You can get rid of the comment using `DebianBanner` option in `sshd_config`. Setting it to `no` and restarting `ssh` server will not show it any more.

Answer (score 2):

The DebianBanner does not work on all Distros (obviously)

The method that work on all distros is the binary replace with Perl, for example:

```
perl -pi -e 's/OpenSSH_7.4/DragonGuru9/g' /sbin/sshd
systemctl restart sshd
```

This can be done on live server as well, and the process must not be stopped.

Take care to replace the "OpenSSH_7.4" with the exact ammount of characters (11 in this case), as you are doing binary character replacement. If you replace it with different ammount of charachers, the binary file will be broken.

Here is how it looks like after the Nmap scan:

[image: Nmap scan custom banner message]